# Deployement HBase Master and hadoop namenode

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I was wondering if there is a general recommendation about the installation of HBase masters according to Hadoop Namenodes.

Comment: What do you mean by general recommendation?

Comment: i'm asking if in general it's more suitable to deploy Hbase master server on the same node as the hadoop namenodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up HBase master on 3 nodes with zookeeper for high availability. In production you should not run any thing on the nodes where namenodes are running.

Namenode is the most critical component for HDFS, if it goes down nothing else is usable on the cluster. So, it will be good to have completely separate nodes to mitigate issues as much as possible.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, and what about putting on the same node HMasterServer and HRegionServer ?

Comment: You should have HRegionServer on the same nodes as datanodes and HMasterServer on 3 different nodes where you do not run datanodes or any other slaves. All Masters should not be shared with other masters or slaves.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers ! it's realy helpfull, do you have any link where they explain why we need to do so ?

Comment: I run a youtube channel called itversity and it has complete details about setting up Hadoop using both Cloudera and Hortonworks distributions.

Comment: Also please up vote the response, so that it will pop up for others when they try to search.

Comment: Done !, thanks a lot i'll check your youtube channel